# React-Bootstrap-Typeahead: Clear on Menu Selection

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-bootstrap-typeahead

In my `React-Bootstrap-Typeahead` I need to set a state var and **clear** in the input immediately to allow new searches. What's happening now is:

1. A list of suggestions is presented
2. When I select a menu item, my `handleChange` is executed correctly
3. The selection is shown in the text field.

I need to set the var `clickedSelection` and reset the input for new searches. Everything should be cleared and closed. (Note: I'm using the `AsyncTypeahead` variation of `React-Bootstrap-Typeahead` .)

```
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState([]);
const [clickedSelection, setClickedSelection] = useState({});

// Fetch Function
const fetchResults = async (token) => {
   setIsLoading(true);
   const response = await axios.get('/myurl/search/' + token); // Axios for Data Fetch
   setSearchResults(response.data); // Set results state var
}

// Handle onChange Function: set 'clickedSelection'
const handleChange = (options) => {
   console.log(JSON.stringify(options[0]);
   setClickedSelection(options[0]);
}

<AsyncTypeahead
    isLoading={isLoading}
    onSearch={(query) => {
       fetchResults(query)
    }}
    option={searchResults}
    labelKey={option => `${option.firstName ${option.lastName}`}
    onChange={handleChange}
/>
```

Comment: Do `setClickedSelection([])` on a menu selection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set a ref on the typeahead and use [the public `clear` method](https://github.com/ericgio/react-bootstrap-typeahead/blob/master/docs/Methods.md#public-methods) to clear the selections in your `onChange` handler:

```
const typeaheadRef = useRef(null);

const handleChange = (selected) => {
  setClickedSelection(selected[0]);
  typeaheadRef.current.clear();
};

return (
  <AsyncTypeahead
    ...
    onChange={handleChange}
    ref={typeaheadRef}
  />
);
```

Working sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/purple-flower-0t5m8